# Способы обновления приложений

Tags: обновление, шаблоны-проектирования

Подскажите пожалуйста, где можно найти информацию по patterns & practices для реализации обновления приложений из интернета, в том числе если приложение для смартфонов. Хотя бы как это правильно назвать и в каком направлении искать.

Comment: Уточняю задачу. Есть приложение работающее на смартфонах (разные платформы) и есть сервер с данными которые меняются каждые 2-3 часа. Данные весят от 20Кб до 4Мб. Обновления кода и так делается с маркета.

Answer (score 1):

Когда мне требовалось автоматическое обновление приложения из интернета, Я писал дополнительную программу, которая висела в фоне и по сути являлась менеджером обновлений, и она периодически опрашивала сервер обновлений на наличие обновок, и как только они появлялись, эта программа скачивала обновление, и ждала завершения работы той программы, обновление для которой она скачала, и как только та программа завершалась, менеджер обновлений заменял файлы этой программы на более новую версию. Дополнительно можно было настроить менеджер обновлений таким образом, чтобы он показывал уведомления в трее.

Этот способ очень похож на способ, который применен в системе обновления google chrome, только не такой продвинутый :)

Еще есть вариант - это при старте самого приложения, в нем запускать отдельный поток, в котором будет выполняться логика поиска и установки обновлений.

ps:// Про обновления ПО на смартфонах, не знаю как у остальных, но андроид обновляет ПО автоматически из google play, либо выдает уведомление о том, что найдены обновления.

Comment: Пожалуй, самый распространённый способ =) Единственное, что не очень хорошо в нём (ИМХО) - по мере установки новых программ в системе появляются over9000 менеджеров, и это притормаживает систему...

Comment: Если Вы поставляете несколько программ, чтио мешает научить ваш менеджер обновлений обновлять нескольки разных видов программ?)

Если не хотите over9k манагеров, тогда стартуйте в контексте вашего приложения отдельный тред, и пусть он опрашивает сервер обновлений. Как тоолько обновления найдены, он качает обновления, показывает пользователю уведомление. Допустим, пользователь нажал кнопку "Обновить". Тогда запускаем скачанную и уже распакованную во временную папку более новую версию программы, аргументами командной строки указываем ей, куда необходимо установить обновления.

Comment: По завершении обновлений запускается опять эта же самая программа, но уже из того места, куда она была изначально установлена, и аргументами командной строки передаем ей путь до временной папки, которую нужно подчистить после успешного обновления. 

Как то так :]

Answer (score 0):

Самообновления часто специфичны для платформы, поэтому искать-читать стоит про каждую конкретную среду.

Напр. [для Adobe Air](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air_update_framework.html) существует родной фреймворк самообновления приложения. Можно считать как одну из Best Practices.

Погуглите по "application self update" или "auto update". Для iPhone например это невозможно. Все апдейты - только через AppStore или Cydia.